# Why does a reversed array equal a regular array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

IE why would code like

```
var strArr = ["a", "b"];
console.log(strArr.reverse() === strArr ? true : false);
```

print true if the reversed array has a different order?

Comment: Because it is done by reference and returns a pointer to the array as [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: `===` already returns a boolean.

Comment: Also note that `[0,1,2] === [0,1,2]` --> false, since `===` returns true for operands of type object, only if they reference the same object. Contents aren't considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `Array.prototype.reverse()` method morphs the original array to it's reverse and then in addition to that returns a "reference" to this morphed array. Hence the result and the morphed original array becomes the same.

If anyone had asked me before developing this method i would request to  keep the original as it is and return a reversed array; alas apparently it wasn't my call.

Answer (score 6):

Because `reverse` reverses the array [**IN PLACE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), so you are comparing the array with itself.